# How to support patch rest request with protobuf 3

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

We often have use cases where we only want to update a subset fields on a resource. So if we have a resource `Person`:

```
type Person struct {
    Age int
    Name string
    Otherfield string
}
```

Say the calling client only wants to update the `Age` field. How would an endpoint be normally set up to handle this?

I believe this should be done with a `PATCH` request, with only the fields being set as part of the payload, ie:

```
{
    Age: 21
}
```

However, this won't work with proto3 because as far as I know there are no null fields, only default values. This won't work in many cases where the default value is valid.

Comment: The answer is probably same as here: use proto2   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433955/proto3-setting-value-equal-to-default-is-not-recognised-in-runtime?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Looking at Google own protobuf files (e.g. [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/appengine/v1/appengine.proto)), they use FieldMask for partial update.

FieldMask object is passed along with the request, and has the form (in JSON):

```
{
   mask: "Person.Age"
}
```

This allows the client to tell the server which fields they wish to update, without counting on the partial message itself to figure this out.

I think this adds unnecessary complexity on (each!) client, but we couldn't find any other way to achieve partial updates with proto3.

You can see full documentation of FieldMask [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/field-mask).

Note that it can also be used to filter out responses if the client doesn't need the entire object.

Comment: Could you please explain on what level FieldMask does that filtering? On interceptor level? Finally, in service method, we get filtered resource?

Comment: Better later than never - FieldMask does not do any filtering. It's just a data structure that allows the server to get list of fields which the client wants to update. It's up to the server to use it in order to implement the partial update.